# cu does not send TTY response to bash output

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, tty

I am executing the following command, opening a serial console and sending the "LM\r" command to my remote device; for which I get "LM122.0P" as an answer:

```
$ sudo cu -l /dev/AR2300CTRL -s 115200 -h
Connected.
LM^MLM122.0P
~~..
Disconnected.
```

However, when I try to read that answer as an output from cu using the following command, I do not get anythin:

```
$ resp=$(
    echo "LM\r" |\
    sudo cu -l /dev/AR2300CTRL -s 115200 |\
    grep -v 'cu' | grep -v 'onnected.'
)
cu: End of file on terminal
cu: child: Got signal 9
$ echo $resp
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't I be getting the response to the command in the "resp" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that pipeline, the `echo` command will exit as soon as it has written text into the pipe to `cu` and therefore the standard input to `cu` will be closed as soon as `cu` consumes the text from the `echo` command.  That close of standard input will cause `cu` to terminate -- that's why it emits the "End of file on terminal" message.

This will all happen long before the device has had a chance to write anything back to `cu`, so the response message is never collected and delivered into `$resp`.

To fix, do something to keep `cu`'s stdin open for long enough to allow the device response to be sent, collected and written to `cu`'s output.  An easy way to do that is to feed the pipeline from a subprocess that does a `sleep` for a few seconds after the `echo` command.  Something like this:

```
resp=$(
    (echo "LM\r" ; sleep 6) |\
    sudo cu -l /dev/AR2300CTRL -s 115200 |\
    grep -v 'cu' | grep -v 'onnected.'
)
```